# How can I get thicker lines in the legends of a ListLinePlot?

Tags: legending, plotting

I want to have thicker lines in the legends of this plot:

```
historyobjetivomejor = {10, 15, 20, 30, 35}
historyobjetivomedia = {6, 8, 10, 13, 15}
historyobjetivopeor = {6, 3, 5, 7, 8}

ListLinePlot[{historyobjetivomejor, historyobjetivomedia, historyobjetivopeor}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.008]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Generacion", "Objetivo"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, Bold}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Max", "Mea", "Min"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

I was trying with options from other posts, but without good result
My last attemp was

```
ListLinePlot[{historyobjetivomejor, historyobjetivomedia, historyobjetivopeor},  
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.008]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Generacion", "Objetivo"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> [{"Max", "Mea", "Min"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, 20}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 10}], 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`AbsoluteThickness` is another useful approach:e.g.

```
op = Table[AbsoluteThickness[2], {3}];
leg = LineLegend[Automatic, {"Max", "Mea", "Min"}];
ListLinePlot[{historyobjetivomejor, historyobjetivomedia, 
  historyobjetivopeor}, AxesLabel -> {"Generacion", "Objetivo"}, 
 PlotStyle -> op, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

[image]

Varying thickness:
[image]

using:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{historyobjetivomejor, historyobjetivomedia, 
   historyobjetivopeor}, AxesLabel -> {"Generacion", "Objetivo"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Table[AbsoluteThickness[t], {3}], 
  PlotLegends -> leg], {t, Range[2, 5]}]
```

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you very much :-) Off-topic... :-) A curiosity. How do you create the animated gif? :-) Any suggestion?

Comment: @MikaIke I use LICEcap freeware...here: http://licecap.en.softonic.com/ is a site but you can search if does not suit your platform

Comment: @ubpdqn Thnk you very much. I´ll try it

Answer (score 5):

I don't recall a direct way of doing this with normal legending, but you can accomplish same with something like:

```
ListLinePlot[{historyobjetivomejor, historyobjetivomedia, 
  historyobjetivopeor}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.008]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Generacion", "Objetivo"}, LabelStyle -> {24, Bold}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, {"Max", "Mea", "Min"}, 
                   LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 4}}, 
                   LegendMarkers -> Graphics[{Thickness[.2], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}]}]], 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `"BaseStyle" -> Thickness[.25]` inside `LineLegend` without having to change the thickness in the main plot:

```
ListLinePlot[{historyobjetivomejor, historyobjetivomedia, historyobjetivopeor}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, {"Max", "Mea", "Min"}, "BaseStyle"->Thickness[.25]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this post - this is the easiest way!